# How to backup the SharePoint pages in the Site pages library with PnP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, sitepages

How can I backup my SharePoint pages resided in the Site pages library of my Communication site using PnP PowerShell?

Comment: You want to copy pages from site pages library somewhere else, maybe in same library but within a folder or site pages library in another site?

Comment: Check this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/copy-sites-page-from-one-site-to-another-using-pnp-powershell2. let me know if it works for you. You might need to use `Export-PnPPage` instead of `Export-PnPClientSidePage` based on version of PnP PowerShell you are using.

Comment: What about backup the Sharepoint pages to a folder in my explorer. Is that possible?

Comment: check `Get-PnPFile` works for you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277383/download-file-from-sharepoint-online-with-powershell

Comment: I'm checking the progress of this issue. Did Ganesh Sanap 's answer help you?

Comment: PnP Provisioning engine - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PnP PowerShell available to copy a modern page to another site:

```
#Parameters
$SourceSiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
$DestinationSiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/branding"
$PageName =  "About.aspx"
 
#Connect to Source Site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SourceSiteURL -Interactive
 
#Export the Source page

    $TempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    Export-PnPPage -Force -Identity $PageName -Out $TempFile
     
    #Import the page to the destination site
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $DestinationSiteURL -Interactive
    Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path $TempFile
```

Reference: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/07/sharepoint-online-copy-pages-to-another-site-using-powershell.html#ixzz7y5JXpR5k